# убрать подскакивание в IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

В разметке есть инпуты с содержимым и во всех браузерах содержимое ведет себя нормально
    Но когда запускается сайт через IE - при нажатии на содержимое инпута - оно подскакивает немного вверх и после возвращается на линию обратно, если кликнуть на любое другое поле

```css
.price-controls input {
  width: 50px;
  min-width: 50px;
  max-height: 15px;
  margin: 0;
  color: inherit;
  font: inherit;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="filter-range" aria-label="фильтра стоимости места проживания">
  <div class="filter-range-title">Стоимость в сутки (р):</div>
  <div class="price-controls">
    <label class="min-price">от <input type="text" name="min-price" value="0"></label>
    <label class="max-price">до <input type="text" name="max-price" value="3000"></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

как исправить это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это скролл. Увеличь `max-height` до `20px`. Или вообще убери.

```css
.price-controls input {
  width: 50px;
  min-width: 50px;
  max-height: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  color: inherit;
  font: inherit;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="filter-range" aria-label="фильтра стоимости места проживания">
  <div class="filter-range-title">Стоимость в сутки (р):</div>
  <div class="price-controls">
    <label class="min-price">от <input type="text" name="min-price" value="0"></label>
    <label class="max-price">до <input type="text" name="max-price" value="3000"></label>
  </div>
</div>
```